# How do I include a text file to a qt application?

Tags: xml, qt, file

I have text file from which I need to get data by line by line. So if my application is launched, it can read from the text file to show the information. But I don't want to supply my text file separately along with my application. How to do this?
And well I have to do this using Qt!

I heard like using xml will be a better and easy way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to add a qt resource file (.qrc) to your project

It might look like this:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>file.xml</file>
        <file>files/file2.xml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

After that you have to add that resource file to your project file (.pro)

Like this for example:

```
RESOURCES += myqrcfile.qrc
```

After that you can use that file in your code by using the character **':'** to refer to the file

Maybe like this:

```
QFile data(":/file.xml");
//or
QFile data(":/files/file2.xml");
//etc...
```

Remember that the path that you define for the file(in the qrc) must correspond to the file's location in the filesystem as well.

Hope this helps, for more information I suggest you read the link to the documentation that Gorkem Ercan posted.

Comment: Where are you supposed to place that initial XML?  There's no button to just add an existing file?

Comment: @tarabyte There is. From the menu: File -> New ->  [Files and Classes] Qt -> Qt resource file

Answer (score 9):

[Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: can you give me an example or something like that to use this QResource? I am not findin evn one example program on hwo to use this stuff! :(

Answer (score 5):

Such code works in the Qt 5.2 :

```
QResource common(":/phrases/Resources/Phrases/Common.xml");

QFile commonFile(common.absoluteFilePath());

if (!commonFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    qDebug() << "Unable to open file: " << commonFile.fileName() << " besause of error " << commonFile.errorString() << endl;

    return;
}

QTextStream in(&commonFile);

QString content = in.readAll();
```

Answer (score 4):

Continuing on ExplodingRat's answer.

Using QFile like that doesn't work (at least not in Qt 4.5), but you can use:

```
QResource r( ":/file.xml" );
QByteArray b( reinterpret_cast< const char* >( r.data() ), r.size() );
```